# Chemical Entropy vs. Mathematical Entropy

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, entropy

In high school physics and chemistry classes, we were told that entropy is a measure of disorder in a physical system. For example, molecules that are relatively stationary correspond to a lower entropy whereas molecules that are moving around correspond to a higher entropy.

But in statistics and probability, entropy is written using a [different formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy):

$$ H(X) = - \sum_{i=1}^{n} p(x_i)\log p(x_i). $$

- Is there any relationship between the interpretation of entropy in probability vs. physics/chemistry?
- In probability, is entropy also describing some type of "disorder"?

Thank you!

Comment: Boltzmann's entropy (in thermodynamics) and Shannon's entropy (in information theory) are formally the same one. Whether they are essentially the same entity or not seems to be a philosophical question with no universal consensus, see [this physics.SE posting](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/263197/118910). Anyway, I guess you will get better answers in other SE communities (such as physics.SE).

Comment: @SangchulLee What does "formally the same one" mean? Do you mean that they can be expressed in the same formula?

Comment: @WhatsUp, That is exactly what I meant. :)

Comment: This paper is a classic: https://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/theory.1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

1. Is there any relationship between the interpretation of entropy in probability vs. physics/chemistry?
   Ans. Yes. They are the same.
2. In probability, is entropy also describing some type of "disorder"?
   Ans. My impression is that it is not usual to think this way, but instead about uncertainty.

The Entropies taught in physics and chemistry is the Clausius Entropy:
dS = dQ/T and the Gibb's Entropy which is mathematically the same as Shannon's Entropy. Gibb's Entropy is in fact also the same as the Clausius Entropy.

Most often entropy is interpreted as follows.
"The entropy of a physical system or a random variable is a measure of the degree of uncertainty of 'the state of such a system' or 'variable'."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It is not [that simple](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/500009/304394). That link calls Clausius entropy "thermodynamic" entropy and we know that the formula for its change is $\color{red}{\delta}Q/T$ and not $dQ/T.$

Comment: The main problem in your answer is that Shannon (aka mathematical) and physical/chemical entropies are *not* the same.